# Sql Query - group by month from 1st day up todays date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a record set of sales amount daily with different branches.
For example

```
Date             Amount      Branch
01/01/2014         30          A
01/01/2014         30          B
01/02/2014         40          A
01/02/2014         40          B
01/03/2014         30          A
01/03/2014         30          B
up to feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug
```

What i want to achieve is to group the record monthly based on todays date day.

For example today is 08/11/2014. the range should be 1st day of the month "1" then i will pick the day today which is 11. So the range for all the months is 1-11. See below sample.

```
Date Range for query monthly
01/01/2014-01/11/2014
02/01/2014-02/11/2014
03/01/2014-03/11/2014
04/01/2014-04/11/2014
05/01/2014-05/11/2014
06/01/2014-06/11/2014
07/01/2014-07/11/2014
08/01/2014-08/11/2014
```

Group this date range and get the sum of total sales.

Please help

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? These are different database products.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. "group the total amount per month based on todays date For example today is 08/11/2014. I want to get the total range per month". Do you want the total for the month in the date range you specify? Please give an example of the results you would expect and any input parameters.

Comment: what is the relation for today with the result?

Comment: What's the part with which you are having difficulty?

Comment: I update my post. I mean i will pick the day today and start to 1st day of the month. so may range is 1-11 and i will apply this range also in the previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do most of the work:

```
  SELECT MONTH(date), SUM(amount)
    FROM table_name
   WHERE DAY(date) <= DAY(CURDATE())
     AND date >= YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

**UPDATE**

For the 3 letter month tag, also you'll probably want an ORDER BY to be sure:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b'), SUM(amount)
    FROM table_name
   WHERE DAY(date) <= DAY(CURDATE())
     AND date >= YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY MONTH(date);
```

Comment: Perfact Solution , just add month in select list

Comment: I have follow up question @Arth , The data result of MONTH(date) is in  number "1,2,3,4,5". Is it possible to change it to "jan,feb,mar,apr,may" using sql query?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want by using the following MySQL query:

```
select sum('amount') from 'some_table'
    where dayofmonth('sell_date') >= 1
        and dayofmonth('sell_date') < dayofmonth(currdate())
    group by month('sell_date');
```

I hope it works, did not have some database to test.

You could eventually also group by branch, by adding an additional `, 'branch'` before the query's semicolon.

Comment: NOTE: update the field names as required by the table in your database.

Also, please tell me if it works :)

Comment: maybe the "smaller-than" sign in `and dayofmonth('sell_date') < dayofmonth(currdate())` should be replace by "smaller-than-or-equal" - ` ... <= ...`.

Comment: `dayofmonth('sell_date') >= 1` will always evaluate true for a valid date.

Comment: @arth - you`re right, sorry.. used this a couple of years ago in some statistics module for an online shop.. sometimes they want to see in different portions of months (first decade, second decate.. so sometimes it was 10th -> 20th..)